# how do I get list items and display it in textfield jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm working on a web application and am having difficulty solving this problem.

I have a list item which looks like this:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>My name is great</li>
    <li>I love Music</li>
    <li>I love EPL</li>
</ul>
```

I also have a textbox.

What I am trying to do is to clone or map (whichever is the best method) the list items and add it to my text box value.

Please note that the entire element + the text will be cloned to the textbox value. For example:

```
<li>My name is great</li>
```

will be cloned to the textbox value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you give your textbox an `id`, e.g.:

```
<textarea id="contents"></textarea>
```

Then you can do this with jQuery using:

```
$("#contents").val($("#list").html());
```

Explanation:

- `$("#list").html()` gets the *HTML contents* of the element with id `list`.
- `$("#contents").val()` sets the contents of the element with id `contents`.

One problem with this is that the `html()` function may preserve formatting, so your list elements may be preceded by a bunch of whitespace in the textarea. This may be browser-dependent.

A solution that will trim any leading whitespace:

```
$("#contents").val($("#list").html().replace(/^\s+/gm, ""));
```

This uses the javascript regexp `/^\s+/gm` to trim whitespace from the beginning of all lines of your list HTML.

Comment: Thank you pb2q. you really saved me alot. It works perfectly. But i cant use .text() for <textarea> or textfield. so i changed it to .val()

Comment: @sesanOwolabi my mistake: _text()_ isn't supposed to be used for input elements in a form. _val()_ is correct. I've edited that in my answer.

Comment: Thank you. just a little question and i hope you can help me.

Comment: Thank you. just a little question and i hope you can help me. if i clone the html contents into the list element at the first click event, now, i do i click even at the second time, how do i clean up the first value in the textbox and add the second value that returns from the second click event

Comment: just using _val()_ should reset the entire textarea contents every time. So if I understand you correctly, if on the second click you again call _val(...contents...)_, you shouldn't need to clean up the first value: it should simply be replaced with the new value.

Comment: Alright!! thank you. i didi notice it cleaned up the first value when i clicked on second it. It works perfectly. thanks alot.